# Is it correct to use the verb ‘feel’ with stuff?

Tags: expression-choice

> I felt that my conversations with him was unfulfilling.

> I had the feeling that my conversations with him were unfulfilling.

Can I correctly change either of the above into:

> My conversations with him felt unfulfilling.

To my knowledge, in the above sentence one might use ‘sounded’, but to make it more touchable, can I use ‘felt’.

Comment: For a start "conversations ... was" is incorrect. Number must correlate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a problemless possibility.

[image]

There are lots of examples [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22felt%20unfulfilling%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en).

Answer (score 1):

A conversation in which you are involved *feels* a certain way to you; it might *sound* a certain way to someone else listening to it.